# Simulate Hardware button click

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, hardware, device

How can I simulate Hardware button (Back, Home, Search) click using Expensify test framework, on Real device connected to USB port on my system. Can you please guide changes required (if any) to acheive this..

Answer (score 0):

Without using robotics, I don't believe this can be done on real hardware as it stands today.

I have talked to some of the US Microsoft DPE team about future support, but there has been no progress on this.

This can, however, easily be done on the emulator using steps such as:

```
 Then I press a hardware button "PhoneHardwareButton"
```

where the PhoneHardwareButton enum is one of the values:

```
   Back,
    Home,
    Search,
    Camera,
    VolumeUp,
    VolumeDown,
    Power,
    Menu
```

from https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/blob/master/Server/Core/Tangibles/PhoneHardwareButton.cs